# DLL and TTimer not working

Tags: delphi, dll

I'm doing a project using DLL Injection just for testing purposes. If everything works well maybe I'll use this technique. But so far, I got only problems, maybe because is the first time I'm coding a DLL project. For a quick understand, I'm creating a suspended explorer.exe process and injecting this DLL inside the suspended explorer. Everything was working, but when I tried to put a timer inside the DLL appeared a problem. Look the DLL code:

```
uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Windows,
  ExtCtrls,
  Dialogs;

{$R *.res}
type
  TMyTimer = Class(TTimer)
  public
    procedure OnMyTimer(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  MyTimer: TMyTimer;

procedure EntryPoint(Reason: integer);
begin
  if Reason = DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH then
    begin
      MessageBox(0, 'DLL Injected', 'DLL Injected', 0);
      MyTimer := TMyTimer.Create(nil);
      MyTimer.Interval := 5000;
      MyTimer.OnTimer := MyTimer.OnMyTimer;
      MyTimer.Enabled:= true;
    end
  else
  if Reason = DLL_PROCESS_DETACH then
    begin
      MessageBox(0, 'DLL De-Injected', 'DLL De-Injected', 0);
    end;
end;

procedure TMyTimer.OnMyTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MessageBox(0, 'Timer Running', 'Timer Running', 0);
end;

begin
  DLLProc:= @EntryPoint;
  EntryPoint(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end.
```

Okay, so when I inject the DLL in the suspended explorer.exe process, I receive the message 'DLL Injected'... After this, it should create the timer and every 5 seconds give-me a message of 'Timer Running'... But I don't receive this message, tried everything and nothing works... Any help? Is that a totally mess or what?

Comment: Hint: put a case in your `EntryPoint` with `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`.

Comment: Please enumerate what you're including in "everything."

Comment: Everything is: create a suspended explorer.exe process, inject dll into it and show a message DLL Injected....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Delphi TTimer object is a loose wrapper around the Win32 SetTimer API function. The VCL wrapper creates a hidden window and then calls SetTimer passing that window. The timer then fires by Windows synthesising WM_TIMER messages in the message queue of the thread that called SetTimer. For your scenario, that thread is the remote thread that you created. It therefore follows that you need to dispatch messages in that thread in order for your timer event to fire.

In general I'd question the wisdom of putting the VCL inside an injected DLL. That's surely going to lead to some pain. If all you need the VCL for is for a timer, then it's just simpler to call SetTimer directly.

I also advise you that you will need to create another thread if you want to get much further. At the moment all your injected code is running inside DllMain. Read the documentation for DllMain, and Raymond Chen's articles on the subject. Especially the parts that explain that DllMain executes when the DLL loader lock is held. You are supposed to do nothing of note in DllMain. You are allowed to call CreateThread. Do so and nothing more.

Comment: I'm trying something like this:
  `if Reason = DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH then
    begin
      MessageBox(0, 'DLL Injected', 'DLL Injected', 0);
      SetTimer(0, 0, 3000, @DoTimer);
    `end;
My DoTimer procedure is like this:
 `procedure DoTimer;
begin
  MessageBox(0, 'Timer Running', 'Timer Running', 0);
end;`
I get no messagebox from Timer Running....

Comment: Of course not. You've not grasped the fundamental problem. Namely the lack of a message pump. And you've ignored my advice about DllMain. You need to create a new thread in the DllProc, and in that thread put all your code. In there you need to run a message pump. You know, while GetMessage(...) do begin TranslateMessage(...); DispatchMessage(...); end;

Comment: @user - Note also that there're times you need to use `stdcall`, and a proper callback of course (see: TimerProc). Anyway, before going into proper implementation details, think of this: what happens right after you call SetTimer? Here's what happens: the execution reaches to the `end` of your 'EntryPoint' and right after that your remote thread is detached from your dll. So in what thread the call to the timer proc will run? Perhaps you need to step back and start from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Your previous question had a calling convention problem. The compiler would have told you about it if you had not used @. I told you that then. And yet here you persist in using @. For the love of God, will everybody stop using @ with procedural variables already!!! It's doing my heas in!

Comment: My god is so hard to do this... I started trying to create a TForm class in the dll, and put all my timers and other stuff inside this class, then I create this class and access all the methods like timers, indy http, over this class TForm... Should work?

Comment: You've been told what to do many times. 1. Inside DllProc, create a thread to do the work. 2. In the thread, run a message loop. More generally, if you don't understand what a message loop is, you need to go back to basics. Injection is an advanced topic. Master the basics first. I recommend Petzold.

Comment: Yes I need to keep trying the basics... But sometimes I want to go harder. Anyway I'll keep trying, I got this working with threads, but Injection + Thread = Harder²... So I wanted to avoid threads creating one form. But looks like it's not a solution since I tried and got problems too... Will try with threads, thank you guys... Don't know what answer accept lol!

Answer (score 4):

TTimer depends on Window Messages, therefore you need a message loop for it to function.

Comment: Uhmmm, sorry but what you mean exactly? I need to create the timer inside a procedure for example and not in the entrypoint?

Comment: No, he means that a timer depends on a message pump in order to work. If this DLL doesn't have a message pump, it wouldn't work.

Comment: All examples I saw over internet to do a timer in dll is exactly like this... What is a message pump? Can you example how I'll do that? Sorry for I really don't know what this means...

Comment: Are you familiar with Windows Messages? It's what powers almost all applications. A message pump (or message loop) is what powers those messages through their queue. Depending on how the DLL was loaded, there's a chance that the host app doesn't share its message queue with your DLL, in which case you should create your own (in the form of a custom thread).

Comment: Actually if I were you I would build a custom thread anyway, I commonly build threads inside of DLL's to encapsulate various things, and I also don't use timers inside of threads or DLL's. Instead I let the thread its self power my own queue of requests.

Comment: You use class TThread for this? Is just like build a thread in .exes?

Comment: @user1526124: yes, threads in DLLs work the same way as threads in EXEs.

Comment: @Jerry This is a DLL injected with CreateRemoteThread, the thread that executes the injected code. If that means nothing to you then I suspect you should not be offering advice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It was my understanding a while back that a DLL *might* not be able to get messages from its host, but I couldn't find anything to back that up.

Comment: @Jerry A DLL is just something with code in. Why would messages not be able to cross from host to DLL? And anyway, messages are not sent to DLLs. Messages are sent to windows. Messages are dispatched by message loops. They can live anywhere.